# Inserting new rows into table-1 based on constraints defined on table-2 and table-3

Tags: sql, windows-7, visual-foxpro

I want to append new rows to a table-1 `d:\dl` based on the equality constraint `lower(rdl.subdir) = lower(tr.n1)`, where rdl and tr would be prospective aliases for `f:\rdl` and `f:\tr` tables respectively.
 I get a `function name is missing ).` message when running the following command in VFP9:

```
INSERT INTO d:\dl SELECT * FROM f:\rdl WHERE (select LOWER(subdir)FROM f:\rdl in (select LOWER(n1) FROM f:\tr))
```

I am using the `in` syntax, instead of the alias based equality statement `lower(rdl.subdir) = lower(tr.n1)` because I do not know where to define aliases within this command.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the best way to get something like this working is to first make the query work and give you the results you want, and then use it in INSERT.

In general, in SQL commands you assign aliases by putting them after the table name, with or without the keyword AS. In this case, you don't need aliases because the ones you want are the same as the table names and that's the default.

If what you're showing is your exact code and you're running it in VFP, the first problem is that you're missing the continuation character between lines.

You're definitely doing too much work, too. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO d:\dl ;
  SELECT * ;
    FROM f:\rdl ;
      JOIN f:\tr ;
        ON LOWER(rdl.subdir) = LOWER(tr.n1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original code for readability, so my exact code is on one line only. I want to use aliases because the actual table names are very long.

Comment: I still get my original error message upon submitting the partial query starting from the `select` statement in the VFP9 command prompt (VCP). Is it possible or necessary to use `;` syntax on VCP?

Comment: It is possible to use ; at command prompt. Just use Ctrl+enter after ; instead of enter. It is not a must but increases readability of your code. Also instead of writing as f:\rdl write it as ("f:\rdl").

Comment: The `join` command causes the insert statement to fail since _d:\dl_ has as many columns as _f:\rdl_, but the joined table contains additional columns from _f:\tr_. I only want to apply `select` and `insert into` on _f:\rdl_ columns to transfer them to _d:\dl_. Is there a work around for the `join` command other than creation of a temporary table where I would delete extraneous columns before insertion into _d:\dl_?

Comment: SELECT rdl.* will give you only the rdl columns.